# Redirect Script PHP

Tags: php, redirect, youtube

Well, I want to have a redirect script on my server.

I want it to take the text after the URL, and redirect it to a website.

The one I have right now looks like this:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];
header("Location: http://youtube.com/watch?v=".$url);
?>
```

That makes the URL looks like : http://mywebsite.com/?url=YOUTUBE CODE HERE

But, I don't want it to look like that, I want the URL to look like this : http://mywebsite.com/YOUTUBE CODE HERE 
and that will redirect the user to the YouTube video.

Thanks

Comment: That must be done with URL rewriting. What web server are you using? (PHP isn't even necessary)

Comment: not a php issue.  What web server are you using?

Comment: If your running Apache then you can make a .htaccess in your root directory that sets a rewriterule. RewriteRule ^youtube/(.*)$ youtubefilethattakesinvars.php?url=$uservar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve that, you need to use .htaccess and mod_rewrite on apache, or a similar technology.

basic examle:

/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^v/(.*)$ v/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

/v/index.php:

```
<?php 
  $url = $_GET['url'];
  header("Location: http://youtube.com/watch?v=" . $url);
?>
```

Comment: Can I do that to sub directories?

Comment: sure, just do something like
`RewriteRule ^yourfolder/(.*)$ your-php-file.php?url=$1`

Comment: That doesn't work, and it changed the sub directory's index page, to the root index page. :S

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want. If the php file is in the subfolder too then `RewriteRule ^yourfolder/(.*)$ yourfolder/your-php-file.php?url=$1` will do the job. You will need to look into url rewriting.

Comment: My .htaccess is in the root directory, and my index.php is in my sub directory "v". 
I've tried that in my .htaccess, and in the sub directory's index.php, I wrote :
<?php $url = $_GET['url'];
header("Location : http://youtube.com/watch?v=" . $url);?>
But that didn't work.

Comment: I updated the answer above, so that it should work for you. You also had a typo (;) in your php.

Comment: hmm, it works for me. be sure you have mod_rewrite for apache installed. `phpinfo();` should tell you that.

Comment: Okay, I got it to redirect, but now, it's sending me to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=index.php

Comment: Don't worry, I got it to work, thank you very much man, I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into URL rewriting.  Here's a tutorial on how to do it on Apache servers:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP itself its possible in this way:

http://www.mywebsite.com/your-php-file.php?{YOUTUBECODE}

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET as $tmp=>$null) {
  $redirect = $tmp;
  break;
}

header("Location: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$redirect");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use **mod_rewrite** for such a simple task much quicker solution is

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Just trim the URL from things you don't need.

Comment: I'm new to PHP, so I don't know how to trim my website URL and keep the YouTube video code. :\

Comment: In your case $url = ltrim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' ); should do.